# how can I access nested array and loop through the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

I am fetching data from Yelp Api and I am trying to access nested  array but I can not .

```
function categories (){
    props.RestaurantsData.forEach((element,index) => {
      console.log(element.categories)
    });
```

I get response like this.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "alias": "seafood",
    "title": "Seafood",
  },
  Object {
    "alias": "burgers",
    "title": "Burgers",
  },
  Object {
    "alias": "newamerican",
    "title": "American (New)",
 

  },
]
```

when I try `categories.title`. I keep getting `undefined`. How can I access all the titles ?

Comment: What do you get when you just console.log(element)? Or even console.log(props.RestaurantsData)

Answer (score 2):

```
function categories (){
    props.RestaurantsData.forEach((element,index) => {
      var items = element.categories;
                items.forEach((item,index) => {
                    console.log(item.title);
            });
    });
}
```

Categories is an array in itself with objects, you iterated through restaurantData, but not through categories, so it's a simple thing just loop through the categories for each restaurant;

categories.title implies there's only one title per categories, as a single object, but your return has many items as it's an array, or multiple categories;

If you wanted the first category, you'd want to use your same code but access the first object in the categories array like so: element.categories[0].title; the above example just loops through them all.